# Searching through NSMutableArray of objects with NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

**The question is solved, here is how I fixed it for future reference for noobs like me**
I needed to remove the white-spaces:
        `ship.countryOfbuild =  [[elements objectAtIndex:0] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];`

And I had to change the predicate like this:     `NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(countryOfBuild contains[cd] %@) OR (shipBuilder contains[cd] %@) OR (name contains[cd] %@) OR (owner contains[cd] %@)",searchText, searchText, searchText, searchText];`

*Original question*

I'm using [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-add-search-bar-uitableview/) to add a search bar to my project. I got the tableview all working, but the search function is crashing the app. The way I search now is:

```
-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                searchText];

searchResults = [searchContent filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}
```

The `searchContent`is a mutable array read from a .csv-file like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSString* pathToFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ships" ofType: @"csv"];

NSString *file = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pathToFile encoding:  NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

NSArray *allLines = [file componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];


searchContent           = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


for (NSString* line in allLines) {
    NSArray *elements = [line componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
    
    CargoShips* ship = [[CargoShips alloc]init];
    ship.countryOfbuild =  [elements objectAtIndex:0];
    ship.shipBuilder =     [elements objectAtIndex:1];
    ship.hullHashtag =     [elements objectAtIndex:2];
    ship.name =            [elements objectAtIndex:3];
    ship.owner =           [elements objectAtIndex:4];
    ship.shipOperator =    [elements objectAtIndex:5];
    ship.shipDelivery =    [elements objectAtIndex:6];
    ship.shipFlag =        [elements objectAtIndex:7];
    ship.shipClass =       [elements objectAtIndex:8];
    ship.powerPlant =      [elements objectAtIndex:9];
    ship.HP =              [elements objectAtIndex:10];
    ship.speed =           [elements objectAtIndex:11];
    ship.cargoSystem =     [elements objectAtIndex:12];
    ship.numberOfTanks =   [elements objectAtIndex:13];
    ship.size =            [elements objectAtIndex:14];
    [self.searchContent   addObject:ship];
}
```

I would like the search to search through all 15 pieces of the object (name, size, shipclass etc)

Currently, this crashes with the error:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't use in/contains operator with collection <CargoShips: 0x714e1b0> (not a collection)'`

CargoShips is my NSObject class.

How do I fix the NSPredicate to search through an `NSMutableArray`with objects without crashing?

Here is the full code if that makes stuff easier http://pastebin.com/sw12GwHK

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get this error because a ship is not a collection, so you can't use contains -- I think you need to search for a particular field in your ship object, and use LIKE not CONTAINS:

```
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.shipBuilder LIKE[cd] %@",searchText];
```

With LIKE you can use wild cards in the search. You could also use BEGINSWITH or ENDSWITH to search for the beginning or end of words.

Comment: This is great, it does not crash anymore atleast. But 1) The search always returns empty. (In log and on screen) and 2) How do I make it search all 15 fields? Thanks:)

Comment: @OscarApeland, first you need to find out why this doesn't work. You need to do some logging. Log self.searchContent to make sure it has what you want in it. Then try logging self.searchContent[0][@"shipBuilder"], and see if that returns what you expect.

Comment: Logging searchContent gives me a lot of `   "<CargoShips: 0x758c700>",
    "<CargoShips: 0x758c900>",
    "<CargoShips: 0x758cb10>",` stuff like these. About 450, the amount of lines in my .csv data source. self.searchContent[0][@"shipBuilder"] Crashes the app with a `[CargoShips objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb9e9370
2013-01-31 19:27:57.323 LNG[35488:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',` Error code.

Comment: So i'm guessing I am reading the data into my searchContent array in a bad way. Or that i'm predicating it wrong.

Comment: @OscarApeland, i may have told you wrong on that last log. shipBuilder is a property of a ship object, so you should log [self.searchContents[0] shipBuilder]

Comment: That properly logs the first shipBuilder in the array of objects. Correct object logs. So that means my fault is in the predicate?

Comment: @OscarApeland, it would seem so, unless your search term just isn't in your objects. Try BEGINSWITH, and see if that works. I can't see why this isn't working now.

Comment: @OscarApeland, I just tested the code I gave you in one of my projects, and it worked fine with either LIKE or BEGINSWITH. So, that predicate is ok. You might want to try, from within the filterContentForSearchText: method, logging both searchText and searchContent to make sure they both have the right value at that point in your code.

Comment: This is my code now http://pastebin.com/X3L0tBBM . See anything obviously wrong here? Searchtext logs correctly, and as stated previously, the searchContent array seems to be fine. I can't really see whats the problem now.

Comment: Forgot to enable obj-c syntax. more readable version: http://pastebin.com/s4w77TUv

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23739/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-oscar-apeland)

Comment: @OscarApeland, I found the problem with the table view. It seems you can get away without the "if cell == nil"  clause for a regular table, but not for the search results table. I changed a few things, including the cell in the storyboard. I deleted the custom cell, dragged in a regular UITableViewCell, and changed its type to "subtitle" (and gave it the identifier "Cell"). Here's the link to the updated .m file. http://pastebin.com/yxuemhy4

Comment: Wow, great! Even though everything else is flawless, this still does somehow return empty search results (in log and on interface) Did it work for you? Pasted your exact file and did what you did to the storyboard.

Comment: @OscarApeland, that's puzzling. The search works for me. Send me an email at rdelmar@comcast.net and I'll send you back the whole project.

Comment: As the error seems to be on my side, I'll accept this as you have done an incredible job helping me to figure this stuff out.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `SELF` in your predicate, since that will use the actual instance of a CargoShip. In your linked example `SELF` works good, since it's an `NSString`.

You can for instance do something like:

`@"(countryOfBuild contains[cd] %@) OR (shipBuilder contains[cd] %@)"`. etc. etc.

Comment: Doing so instead like this: `[NSPredicate
                                    predicateWithFormat:@"(countryOfBuild contains[cd] %@) (shipBuilder contains[cd] %@)",
                                    searchText];` returns error: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "(countryOfBuild contains[cd] %@) (shipBuilder contains[cd] %@)"'` Am I doing it wrong/how do I do it properly?

Comment: Sorry, forgot some part of the syntax -> `) OR`

Comment: HOLY FLYING HAMSTERS IT WORKS@! :D Thanks alot!

Comment: Great solution I used it like this NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"eventName contains[cd] %@",searchText];
  self.searchReturnedResults = [[NSArray alloc] init];
  self.searchReturnedResults = [[MKEventStore sharedEventStore].events filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];

Answer (score 3):

I use:

```
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.youProperty contains[c] %@", searchString];
searchArrayObjects = [arrayObjects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
```

[Links to documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html)

Comment: This question is more than a year old, I solved it long ago, but thanks :P